# File Read concatenate

Tags: python, operating-system, os.walk

```
import os

print("root prints out directories only from what you specified")
print("dirs prints out sub-directories from root")
print("files prints out all files from root and directories")
print("*" * 20)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/var/log"):
    print(root)
    print(dirs)
    print(files)
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to store the names in a text file and then be able to use different operations on it, one such as concatenation, and find/replace.

Comment: This question is too broad, please ask something more specific or add more details.

Comment: `[os.path.join(r,f) for (r, ds, fs) in os.walk('/var/log') for f in fs]` will give you list of all files under `/var/log` which you can do whatever needed with.